# SqlException when inserting multiple records table with unique index in linq-sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, unique-index

I have a sql table with a PK column `ItemID` and unique index on column `Value`.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Item](
    [ItemID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [int] NULL
)

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Item_Value_U_NC] ON [dbo].[Item] 
(
    [Value] ASC
)
```

I'm inserting multiple records (batch insert/update) in the table using linq-sql. I do an "exists" check before inserting the record.

```
void MultipleInserts(List<int> values)
{
    using (var db = new DBDataContext())
    {
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            var dbItem = db.Items
                    .Where(x => x.Value == value)
                    .SingleOrDefault();

            if (dbItem == null)
            {
                var Item = new Item()
                {
                    Value = value
                };
                db.Items.InsertOnSubmit(Item);
            }
        }
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

I get the below exception due to the unique index if the list has the same values. `Item` table has no records.

```
var values = new List<int>();
values.Add(1);
values.Add(1);
MultipleInserts(values);
```

Exception message:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Item' with unique index 'IDX_Item_Value_U_NC'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

How do I avoid this?

EDIT: I cannot do single inserts so I cannot move the `db.SubmitChanges()` call inside the for loop.

EDIT2: The answers posted so far deal with fixing the data rather than a way within linq-sql. I have put a simple example with a list of ints. But in reality I have a list of object graph to inserts and every item hits multiple tables for insert/update. I found a way using linq `DataContext`'s `ChangeSet` (`DataContext.GetChangeSet().Deletes`, `DataContext.GetChangeSet().Inserts`, etc.) which I have posted as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are inserting them both at the same time.  Neither of them exist until you actually call `db.SubmitChanges()`

Try moving the `db.SubmitChanges()` inside the loop and that should solve the problem.

ETA: Another possibility would be changing your loop from:

```
foreach (var value in values)
```

to

```
foreach (var value in values.Distinct())
```

Comment: Eric, I understand that. I have to do multiple inserts. I cannot do single inserts.

Comment: @hlpPy - Just updated my answer.  Alternatively, you might be able to mark the property as unique in your dbml (can't remember exactly how you do that though, it's been a while)

Comment: I actually have a unique index on 2 columns (I simplified the question). That unique property in the dbml trick would not work in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this was just a typo in your question, but the Where clause in your LINQ statement is `.Where(x => x.Value = value)`. I think you want the comparison operator here, not assignment.  Try changing your LINQ statement to the following:

```
var dbItem = db.Items 
    .Where(x => x.Value == value) 
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

In addition, if you're using .NET 3.5 or later, you could replace your `List<T>` with [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005.aspx) to guarantee that you only have unique values.

Comment: Jon, this is trivial - but `HashSet<T>` was introduced available in 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than fixing the data, I found a way to work within linq-sql using the DataContext's ChangeSet. The data in the example is simple but it could be an object graph which hits multiple tables and would be difficult to fix.

I first look in the `db.Items` and then check the DataContext's ChangeSet (`db.GetChangeSet().Inserts`) to find the item and insert if it not found.

```
void MultipleInserts(List<int> values)
{
    using (var db = new DBDataContext())
    {
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            // look in db first
            var dbItem = db.Items
                    .Where(x => x.Value == value)
                    .SingleOrDefault();

            if (dbItem == null)
            {
                // look in ChangeSet second
                var cachedItem = db.GetChangeSet().Inserts
                    .OfType<Item>()
                    .Where(x => x.Value == value)
                    .SingleOrDefault();

                if (cachedItem == null)
                {
                    var Item = new Item()
                    {
                        Value = value
                    };
                    db.Items.InsertOnSubmit(Item);
                }
            }
        }
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```